# C++ object without subclasses?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is a way to declare an object in c++ to prevent it from being subclassed. Is there an equivalent to declaring a final object in Java?

Comment: Do you really want to stop a class from being subclassed? It is very difficult to really know about the future usage of a class.

Comment: Stopping a class from being subclassed is a real need in C++. You will not need virtual methods and will save 4 bytes in each instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [C++ FAQ, section on inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#final-classes)

> This is known as making the class
>   "final" or "a leaf." There are three
>   ways to do it: an easy technical
>   approach, an even easier non-technical
>   approach, and a slightly trickier
>   technical approach.
>
> **The (easy) technical approach** is to
>   make the class's constructors private
>   and to use the [Named Constructor Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom)
>   to create the objects. No one can
>   create objects of a derived class
>   since the base class's constructor
>   will be inaccessible. The "named
>   constructors" themselves could [return
>   by pointer if you want your objects
>   allocated by `new`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#static-create-methods) or they could [return
>   by value if you want the objects
>   created on the stack](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom).
>
> **The (even easier) non-technical
>   approach** is to put a big fat ugly
>   comment next to the class definition.
>   The comment could say, for example, `//
>   We'll fire you if you inherit from
>   this class` or even just `/*final*/
>   class Whatever {...};`. Some
>   programmers balk at this because it is
>   enforced by people rather than by
>   technology, but don't knock it on face
>   value: it is quite effective in
>   practice.
>
> **A slightly trickier technical approach**
>   is to exploit [virtual inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-where).
>   Since [the most derived class's ctor
>   needs to directly call the virtual
>   base class's ctor](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-ctors), the following
>   guarantees that no concrete class can
>   inherit from class `Fred`:

```
 class Fred;

 class FredBase {
 private:
   friend class Fred;
   FredBase() { }
 };

 class Fred : private virtual FredBase {
 public:
   ...
 };
```

> Class `Fred` can access `FredBase`'s ctor,
>   since `Fred` is a friend of `FredBase`,
>   but no class derived from Fred can
>   access FredBase's ctor, and therefore
>   no one can create a concrete class
>   derived from `Fred`.
>
> If you are in extremely
>   space-constrained environments (such
>   as an embedded system or a handheld
>   with limited memory, etc.), you should
>   be aware that the above technique
>   might add a word of memory to
>   `sizeof(Fred)`. That's because most
>   compilers implement virtual
>   inheritance by adding a pointer in
>   objects of the derived class. This is
>   compiler specific; your mileage may
>   vary.

Comment: I actually don't plan on restricting subclassing I was just curious cause I'm learning c++ from a java background, thanks for the detailed answer +1

Answer (score 7):

No, there isn't really a need to. If your class doesn't have a virtual destructor it isn't safe to derive from it anyway. So don't give it one.

You can use this trick, copied from [Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation):

```
class Usable;

class Usable_lock {
    friend class Usable;
private:
    Usable_lock() {}
    Usable_lock(const Usable_lock&) {}
};

class Usable : public virtual Usable_lock {
    // ...
public:
    Usable();
    Usable(char*);
    // ...
};

Usable a;

class DD : public Usable { };

DD dd;  // error: DD::DD() cannot access
        // Usable_lock::Usable_lock(): private  member
```

In C++0x (and as an extension, in MSVC) you can actually make it pretty clean:

```
template <typename T>
class final
{
private:
    friend T; // C++0x, MSVC extension

    final() {}
    final(const final&) {}
};

class no_derived :
    public virtual final<no_derived> // ah, reusable
{};
```

Answer (score 2):

**NO**.

The closest you can come is to declare the constructors `private`, then provide a static factory method.

Comment: If you did this, couldn't it still be subclassed if you did `class Derived : private Base`? (C++ noob here)

Comment: @dreamlax, no, it doesn't help. Private inheritance only further restricts access to the base class' members.

Comment: @Péter: Good to know. Time to get my C++ books back from my colleagues.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent language construct for this in C++.

The usual idiom to achieve this technically is to declare its constructor(s) private. To instantiate such a class, you need to define a public static factory method then.

Answer (score 2):

As of C++11, you can add the final keyword to your class, eg

```
class CBase final
{
...
```

The main reason I can see for wanting to do this (and the reason I came looking for this question) is to mark a class as non subclassable so you can safely use a non-virtual destructor and avoid a vtable altogether.

Comment: You can? I can't find that in my copy of the standard.

Comment: I don't know about the standard, I haven't read it, but it is documented in Bjarne Stroustrup’s C++11 - the new ISO C++ standard at <http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#final>

Comment: Ok, now I actually found this use in the language standard. There are no examples like `class Base final`, but its use is mentioned in the text of the first paragraphs of chapter 9: "If a class is marked with the *class-virt-specifier* `final` and it appears as a *base-type-specifier* in a *base-clause* (Clause 10), the program is ill-formed.". Meaning that `class Base final` cannot be derived from.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way really.  The best you can do is make all your member functions non-virtual and all your member variables private so there is no advantage to be had from subclassing the class.